# How to fix “SQL Server does not exist or access denied.” when connecting a Visual Studio C++ console app to a Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to connect a Microsoft SQL Server database in a console application in Visual Studio 2019.

I am getting an error: SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

I suspected that I might have the wrong connection string and so I used SQLDriverConnect function with SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE_REQUIRED to prompt a window so I can manually select which server I want to connect to.

```
SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnHandle, desktopHandle, (SQLCHAR*)"", SQL_NTS, OutConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE_REQUIRED)
```

Note: OutConnectionString is 5th param, InConnectionString is 3rd param

With this, I was able to print the connection string returned to OutConnectionString and I was also able to access the database and print its contents.

But when I tried to copy the OutConnectionString into the InConnectionString, it still comes back to the same error.

```
SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnHandle, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DSN=JoelDB;UID=myID;PWD=myPW;WSID=JE-ACCOUNTS;DATABASE=myDB;Network=DBMSSOCN;Address=JE-ACCOUNTS\SQLEXPRESS,1433", SQL_NTS, OutConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
```

I already tried creating an exception for port 1433 in windows firewall and other suggestions from this site but to no avail.

https://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/database-does-not-exist-access-denied/

I know that the connection exists since I was able to do it via the SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE_REQUIRED parameter and I am also able to manually load the database in Visual Studio via Tools > Connect to Database.

I want to manually put the connection string in the code since it is inconvenient to click through the prompted window to select the database I want every time I run/debug the program.

Comment: `\S` in a double-quoted string will be just `S` I think. You need to escape that backslash: `\\S`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just by removing the address and the network in the connection string.

```
SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnHandle, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DSN=JoelDB;UID=myID;PWD=myPW;WSID=JE-ACCOUNTS;DATABASE=myDB;", SQL_NTS, OutConString, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)
```